# Getting Multiple Errors In PHP code

Tags: php

I am trying to use this file manager called ["Php Win2K File Manager"](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/showcode.asp?txtCodeId=1045&lngWid=8)
But I am receiving these errors below

> Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\explorer.php on line 166
>   Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\explorer.php on line 214
>   Warning: opendir(c:/inetpub/wwwroot/,c:/inetpub/wwwroot/) [function.opendir]: The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\explorer.php on line 91
>   Warning: opendir(c:/inetpub/wwwroot/) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\explorer.php on line 91

Why is this? Is it because Im running this on a Linux Server instead of Win2K?

[My page](http://recksite.org/errors.html)

Comment: A Win2k server. Kill me.

Comment: Erg... if you were running a Linux server your file paths wouldn't be rooted in a `C:` drive...

Comment: You will generally get better results if you post code directly in your question (the error messages indicate the line numbers; use that as a guide for what lines to post here).

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927067/need-to-have-this-fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call-time pass-by-reference means that a variable is being passed into a function using the `&` operator in front of it.  e.g. (`someFunction(&$var);`).

PHP 5.4 deprecated call-time pass-by-reference which means you cannot pass a variable by reference in the function call, the correct way is to define the function so the variable is always passed by reference.  The function definition for the above call would look like:

```
function someFunction(&$iAmByReference) {
    $iAmByReference = 42;
}
```

When you call it, you don't need to precede the variable with the `&`, the call just looks like:

```
$x = 32;
someFunction($x);
echo $x; // 42
```

You will have to modify the code so that the function definitions declare the variable as a reference variable, and remove the `&` from any function calls.

You say you are running on Linux, but given the PHP error messages it appears you are still on Windows.  PHP says your script is `C:\xampp\htdocs\test\explorer.php` which is a Windows path.

Most likely `$_GET['dir']` is incorrect, or the script is determining paths wrong.  Not sure what's going on there, I'd have to see how you were accessing the script.  In the first case, it looks like its trying to open a path that is actually 2 paths separated by commas.